# How do I create a remote git repository in EGit and link it to an existing Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using Eclipse Helios and EGit.  I am new to Git.  I have an existing Eclipse project for an Android app I would like to place in Git.  Can someone please share some instructions on how to setup a Git repo on a shared folder, and place the existing project into this git repo using EGit?  I have tried a variety of options with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same question (how to do it in Eclipse / eGit), and I just found the answer to the question stated in the title :

1. **either** go to `Window` > `Show View` > `Other...` then select `Git` > `Git repositories` **or** click the Git repositories icon in the set of icons in the right
2. expand the repository to see "Remotes", right click and `Create Remote`
3. choose the option : fetch will tell eclipse you're only allowed to read (which is the correct option if you don't want/have the right to push on that repo). then name that remote repository like you want (the first is usually named "origin", but you can have "prod", "test-server", ...)
4. click on change to specify the uri of the repository. You can paste on the first field the complete uri you would type after "git clone"; if in GitHub you first copy the uri then it might be automatically filled in
5. "Finish" then "Save and Push" or "Save and Fetch" according to what you chose in 3°

Also, for creating a new project in Eclipse from an existing git repository with eGit, all you have to do is to go in `File > Import...`and choosing Git/Projects from Git. Then follow the steps

Comment: +1, this is the right answer if you want the repo details to be remembered, so you can easily push again in future

Comment: @Asenar Very good answer! I have this page bookmarked. Wonder why there are no upvotes for this answer. It is so simple to accomplish this, yet so hard to find relevant information. Saved me a to of headache.

Comment: Thanks you ;) My answer is pretty recent, the question (and the validated answer) were 2 years old. I assume this feature wasn't well done or working in 2011.

Comment: In Eclipse Mars (2015) there is no "Remotes" under "Git Repositories" as far as I can see.

Comment: did you installed eGit ?

Comment: My 3/2021 version of Eclipse does not offer the ability to "expand" to see remotes, as described in step #2.

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope the changes are accurate. For step 4 it might should be "Add" instead of "change". Also for step 3 I think I did not see that, it might be removed or it might not always be relevant.

Answer (score 12):

You can do everything from the command line instead:

Do this in the root of the project:

```
git init
```

Do the same in the folder where you want your blessed or central repository:

```
git init --bare
```

In the local repository, add a readme file and commit it:

```
echo "testing" > readme
git add readme   
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now link and push your changes to the central repository:

```
git remote add origin //server/share/repodir
git push -u origin master
```

Hope this gets you started.

You can use egit later if you like, but there is nothing wrong with using git separately.

Comment: What does `//server/share/repodir` means? Let's suppose I have a central GIT repository on localhost and at /home/myuser/repo.git. Is it `//localhost/home/myuser/repo.git`? If so it says: `fatal: '//localhost/home/myuser/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: In this case you can simply use the path to your repo. In linux and mac it would be something like `~/dev/path/to/your/repo` or on windows with msysgit `/c/dev/path/to/your/repo`.

Comment: Doesn't using the command line instead kind of defeat the purpose of having an IDE?

Answer (score 6):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

If you only want one project in your git repo, Team>Share Project will turn that project into a git repo.  You can then create another repo on your share, and push your project repo to the shared folder repo.

If you want a repo with multiple projects, your best bet is to create the project in an external location to the workspace.  Then you can create the git repo in the folder above your project.

Comment: thx for the useful link! Followed this http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Pushing_a_Local_Repository_to_GitHub and it works fine

Comment: Thanks. The confusing thing about EGit is when you create a repo it does not say if it is a 'local' or 'remote' repo. My first time I thought I was creating a remote repo and my project got moved out of my workspace to the remote file system. Oops!  So really EGit is ALWAYS just creating a repo.