# pull from non local git repository using Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, pull

I am trying to do a "pull" from my git repository on bitbucket, using Egit (Eclipse). I can do "push" without any problems, but when I try to pull I get the error message:

> The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key
>   branch.master.merge found in configuration

I have tried creating new branches from both eclipse and bitbucket, but the can't seem to "communicate". When I create a new branch in eclipse, it's automatically a local ( which it shouldn't be)

How can I set up my eclipse and bitbucket for "pulls" (not local)? 
(I am a bit confused as I thought I was connected to the repository, since push works)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309).
The push works because of the **[default push policy "`simple`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598713/6309)**.

With Egit:

Access `"Configure Branch`":

- Go to "`Git Repositories`" view,
- Expand the branches, local

Then:

- Right-click your checked-out local branch that can't pull
- Select "`Configure Branch...`":

  - For "`Upstream Branch:`", put "refs/heads/yourBranch"
  - For "Remote:", put "origin"
  - Leave "Rebase" unchecked
  - Hit OK

Comment: I still get the same error :( 

I don't if this is why it went wrong, but I had to enter the "Remote" manually ("origin"). Is that bad?


I am getting this error:
The current branch is not configured for pull. No value for key "remote.origin.url"found in configuration. Not the same as before. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: About the "remote key": origin.. what does that mean? Is it some kind of variable that I should set in eclipse? And should I not connect with my bitbucket with a link or something? Everytime I want to "push", it ask me for the link to my bitbucket, could this be the source of the problem maybe?`

Comment: @user68621 yes, it is the source: the bitbucket url should be registered in a remote named `origin`: you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/18056388/6309 in order to register that '`origin`' url.